# While using angular js with web2py which method to include file should be preferred - using ng-include or using python include and why?

Tags: angularjs, web2py

My project has front-end in angular and backend in web2py. Partials can be included using web2py include as well. Is there some gain to python over angular or angular over python in speeding up the page load time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky to answer because it may depend on the nature of the content (and how it is being served) and whether you're interested in time to first byte or time to full page render (or something in between). Your best bet is to do some testing (keeping in mind that the results may differ when the server is under heavy load, as processing web2py templates consumes CPU time).

Note, all `{{include}}` statements in web2py templates are processed on the server before the full HTML page is returned to the browser. This means there is only one network request, though some additional processing on the server to handle the included templates (note, compiling the views, which should be done in production, will speed things up quite a bit).

The `ng-include` directive, on the other hand, is executed via Javascript in the browser, so it results in an additional network request back to the server, which will take additional time.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I am trying the same way.